# Run length encoding python; String index out of range error

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to implement run length encoding into python with this code.

When I run it I get string index out of range error, not sure what is causing the error though

```
text="aaabbbcc"

def encode(text):

    prev = text[0]
    lentext = len(text)
    i = 1
    while prev == text[i] and i < lentext:
        i += 1
    return prev + str(i) + encode(text[i:])

print(encode(text))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you can check if i is less than the text length, you already try to access the ith element of text, which causes the exception. Instead, write your while loop as:

```
while i < lentext and prev == text[i]:
```

This will make sure `i` is in range before trying to access that index of text.

Also note that if you are going to use a recursive algorithm, you need a base case to exit the chain of recursive calls from. Probably something like the following at the top of your function:

```
if not text:
    return ""
```

So all together:

```
text="aaabbbcc"

def encode(text):
    if not text:
        return ""
    prev = text[0]
    lentext = len(text)
    i = 1
    while i < lentext and prev == text[i]:
        i += 1
    return prev + str(i)+ encode(text[i:])

print(encode(text))
```